# Imports within an installed Python package

Tags: python, package, python-import, python-module

Consider the following directory structure for an installed Python package:

```
project/
    project/
        __init__.py
        file1.py
        file2.py
        module/
            __init__.py
            file3.py
    setup.py
```

In order to access a function in `file2.py` from `file1.py`, one could do

```
from file2 import fun
```

Or

```
from project.file2 import fun
```

Analogously, if from `file1.py` I wanted to access a function in `file3.py`, I could do `from project.module.file3 import function` or `from .module.file3 import function`.

These two options appear to be equivalent. Is there a preferred method, or a relevant difference between the two that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is mostly a matter of personal preference, PEP8 recommends using absolute imports:

```
from project.module.file3 import function
```

rather than relative imports:

```
from .module.file3 import function
```

Absolute imports are more readable and better behaved (better error messages upon failure). BUT, when using absolute imports becomes unnecessarily verbose (use your judgement), using relative imports is an acceptable alternative. See this [PEP8 documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) on imports.